# how to pass IDbContext into DbMigrationsConfiguration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first, dbcontext

Have been implementing Generic Repository, Unit of Work pattern with EF5 Code First from a number of resources and have come up with the following assemblies.

Interfaces, Contexts, Model, Repositories, UnitsOfWork

In the Context assembly I have my migrations folder which contains Configuration.cs

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context.SportsContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context.SportsContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

As you can see this DbMigrationsConfiguration takes in my SportsContext which is also defined in the contexts assembly (Contexts folder)

```
 public class SportsContext : IDbContext
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public SportsContext()
    {
        _context = new DbContext("SportsContext");

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    public IDbSet<T> GetEntitySet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void ChangeState<T>(T entity, EntityState state) where T : class
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = state;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This implements IDbContext which is defined in the Interfaces assembly

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<T> GetEntitySet<T>() where T : class;
    void ChangeState<T>(T entity, EntityState state) where T : class;
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

In my UnitsOfWork assembly I have the following class

```
public class SportUnitOfWork : IUnitofWork
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;

    public SportUnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new SportsContext();
    }

    private GenericRepository<Team> _teamRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Fixture> _fixtureRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Team> TeamRepository
    {
        get { return _teamRepository ?? (_teamRepository = new GenericRepository<Team>(_context)); }
    }

    public GenericRepository<Fixture> FixtureRepository
    {
        get { return _fixtureRepository ?? (_fixtureRepository = new GenericRepository<Fixture>(_context)); }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IDbContext Context
    {
        get { return _context; }
    }

    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

For examples sake I have added the GenericRepository class in the Repositories assembly

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private IDbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public GenericRepository(IUnitofWork uow)
    {
        _context = uow.Context;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) return;

        if (_context == null) return;
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _context.GetEntitySet<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        _context.ChangeState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    public void Remove(T entity)
    {
        _context.ChangeState(entity, EntityState.Deleted);
    }

    public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = FindIncluding(includes);
        return (predicate == null) ? set.FirstOrDefault() : set.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = FindIncluding(includes);
        return (predicate == null) ? set : set.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var set = _context.GetEntitySet<T>();

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var include in includeProperties)
            {
                set.Include(include);
            }
        }

        return set.AsQueryable();
    }

    public int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        var set = _context.GetEntitySet<T>();
        return (predicate == null) ? set.Count() : set.Count(predicate);
    }

    public bool Exist(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        var set = _context.GetEntitySet<T>();
        return (predicate == null) ? set.Any() : set.Any(predicate);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is in the Configuration class which inherits from DbMigrationsConfiguration is expecting a DbContext parameter.

Error is Error  1   The type 'Contexts.Context.SportsContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Contexts.Context.SportsContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.

I can change the SportsContext to also inherit from DbContext but then I need to add a reference to EntityFramework 5 in the UnitsOfWork assembly as we want to possibly change or take out each layer without any reference to underlying models which is why i went with this pattern.

As we are looking at adding further contexts and models in the future so wanted to setup a architecture in that we could just add the context, model and then implement the relevant interfaces as and when needed.

A WebAPI Restful Web Service will be interacting with our data via the SportUnitOfWork, if I have understood the patterns correctly.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could do this or anything that I am doing wrong please let me know

thanks in advance Mark

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using Code First. (Implied by your `new DbContext("SportsContext")` statement.) If this is the case then Code First Migrations will not work anyway.

Comment: I have got round the problem by doing the following

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by doing the following

Changed my SportsContext class to a BaseContext which is abstract

```
public abstract class BaseContext : IDbContext
{
    protected DbContext Context;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public IDbSet<T> GetEntitySet<T>() where T : class
    {
        return Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = GetDbEntityEntrySafely(entity);
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    public void Update<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = GetDbEntityEntrySafely(entity);
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = GetDbEntityEntrySafely(entity);
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        // At the moment we are conforming to server wins when handling concurrency issues
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904

        try
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
        {
            //Refresh using ServerWins
            var objcontext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) Context).ObjectContext;
            var entry = e.Entries;

            objcontext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entry);

            SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private DbEntityEntry GetDbEntityEntrySafely<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = Context.Entry(entity);

        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // Set Entity Key
            var objcontext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) Context).ObjectContext;

            if (objcontext.TryGetObjectByKey(dbEntityEntry.Entity))

            Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        }

        return dbEntityEntry;
    }
}
```

created in the Context folder a new class called FootballContext which inherits from BaseContext.

```
public class FootballContext : BaseContext
{
    public FootballContext(string connectionstringName)
    {
        Context = new BaseFootballContext(connectionstringName);

    }
}
```

Created a new folder called DbContexts

In here created the following classes,

```
public class BaseFootballContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseFootballContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Fixture> Fixtures { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }  
}

public class MigrationsContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<BaseFootballContext>
{
    public BaseFootballContext Create()
    {
        return new BaseFootballContext("FootballContext");
    }
}
```

now my Configuration class can take in the BaseFootballContext as this is a DbContext.

My UnitOfWork class can now set the context to be FootballContext so does not have to reference EntityFramework.

This works with Migrations as well.

Only problem I have now is to figure out how to get this to work in a disconnected environment as I am having a problem reattaching entities and applying updates.